# I don't see content of react project i downloaded. Problem with import (VSC)

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

I downloaded a project from github and trying to run it however after installation of all needed packages i still cant see any content running index.html on live server.
In terminal i can see following message:

`The following dependencies are imported but could not be resolved: [1] [1]   react-router-dom (imported by C:/Users/sebas/Downloads/VIC2-Develop/VIC2-Develop/Frontend/src/components/SignIn.jsx) [1]   react-dom/client (imported by C:/Users/sebas/Downloads/VIC2-Develop/VIC2-Develop/Frontend/src/main.jsx)`

I tried to look at these two files but they look OK. I don't know where is the problem. Please help

Comment: How do you run the project? How did you install the dependencies?

Comment: i run project by using command: npm run all. I installed some packages before also by using np install somepackagename

Comment: This can be anything. You can set this comment to whatever you want in `package.json`